# Apply single mask to a layer group in Sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, sketch-app, mask, pathfinder

I have the following icon:

[image: my icon]

At this point I have tried to reduce the number of paths as much as I could but still this icon consists of multiple shapes.

**Is there a way to combine icon into single shape in Illustrator?**

I need that to apply a single mask to this icon in Sketch. I suspect I can't combine icon into single shape as I tried multiple ways of doing that and as far as shapes don't overlap they will always be separate shapes. So the new question is: **How to apply single mask to a layer group in Sketch?**

P.S. Why do I need that? To make design process more efficient by placing icon into a shared library and be able to change fill color using overrides. Since there are multiple shapes in the icon I need to use mask to each of them so it leaves me with this:

[image: Sketch symbol]

**How to apply a single mask to a whole icon so I could use only single override for a color change?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can apply a mask to a group, but you can very easily work around it by combining shapes into a single shape in Sketch. You just have to drag one shape onto another **in the layers panel on the left**. When you have combined them into one shape, you can apply the mask directly to it.

Here's an illustration of what an uncombined shape in Sketch looks like:

[image: Uncombined]

(Note that the rectangle is a combined shape already; see the little caret to the left - by clicking it you can expand the list of shapes it consists of).

And the combined shape:

[image: Combined]

(As you can see, you can still edit the components of the shape after you combine it, and they do not have to overlap).

Here's what it looks like with a single mask:

[image: Combined with mask]

Hope this is what you were looking for!